# Does aiofile write and read in background avoid blocking the executing thread?

Tags: python, file, aiohttp

I have recently worked with python and I am unsure about asyncio. The program requests a url, then parses a tag for each page and finally writes this to a local file. The program uses the aiofile library to write the tags into the file. I read that aiofile allows one to create an asynchronous file and use its methods like coroutines. Does this mean that while I write my tags into the local file in the background, I can continue to execute other tasks (like request other urls and parse those have been fetched) without having to wait while all tags are written in the local file?

Here is part of the code:

```
async def fetch():
async def parse():

async def write_one(file: IO, url: str, **kwargs) -> None:
    """Write the found HREFs from `url` to `file`."""
    res = await parse(url=url, **kwargs)
    if not res:
        return None
    async with aiofiles.open(file, "a") as f:
        for p in res:
            await f.write(f"{url}\t{p}\n")
        logger.info("Wrote results for source URL: %s", url)
```